# Why aren't key value pairs produced when a list comprehension is used?

Tags: python, dictionary, conditional-statements, list-comprehension, keyvaluepair

I have a dictionary and i'm trying to use a conditional on the key value pairs using list comprehension to filter the dict.  The code doesn't throw an error, but the output is in the wrong format.
The for loop works, but the list comprehension doesn't.  Why?  I would prefer to use list comprehension.

```
news1 = {'check':1,'this':2, 'thing':3, 'out':4, 'dude':5 }
news2 = {'just':1,'for':2, 'antother':3, 'chance':4, 'now':5 }

for item in x:
    if x[item] > 2:
        print item

def list1(x):
    print  ((item, x[item]) for item in x if x[item] > 2)
```

Comment: you don't have `x` defined anywhere in your code

Comment: it should be rather `print [(item, x[item]) for item in x if x[item] > 2]`. In`()` brackets you are creating a generator instead of list comprehension

Comment: If you won't mention what output you are getting, and what you desire, you won't be getting the correct answer here. As we can not read your mind. Also, mention the content of `x`

Comment: that did the trick, thank you!!

Comment: @AbhishekDesai there are 2 answers at the bottom with the same solution, make sure to mark one as the answer!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The round brackets indicate a generator comprehension which is different. Use square brackets:

```
print  [(item, x[item]) for item in x if x[item] > 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

`print [(item, x[item]) for item in x if x[item] > 2]`

Would work because () are used in something else, also x should be defined to something.